# How do I run a terminal command at the same time as executing a C program from terminal

Tags: c, terminal, pipe

I have a C program executable. I will run a terminal command at the same time as I run the program and wonder how I would do that?

```
./program | ps -l -u ${USER} | grep info
```

I put in my username for USER but I get:

> Usage:  ps [options]
>
> Try 'ps --help '   or 'ps --help
>   '  for additional help text.
>
> For more details see ps(1).

Don't know what I do wrong?

Comment: Why would you pipe to the input of `ps`?

Comment: `ps` doesn't read its standard input.  Maybe you wanted: `./program & ps -l -u${USER} | grep info` or something similar.  Don't forget, commands like `ls` and `ps` are just C programs that happen to be supplied with the system.  Otherwise, they're no different from C programs you write.

Answer (score 0):

answering your question as stated in header you want to run

```
./program & ps ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run your `./program` in the background as you `grep` the output from `ps`:

```
./program & ps -l -u ${USER} | grep info
```

the `&` puts `./program` in the background where as `|` is used to pipe the output of one command to another